# Can I use a Media Center remote control with my Dell Inspiron 9100

Tags: windows-vista, windows-media-center

I have a Dell Inspiron 9100 with a front IR receiver built in.
Is there a way for the IR receiver to be used with a Media Center remote (or any other remote) to control the Vista Media Center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I discovered quite by accident that it is possible - i think you just need the drivers to be installed.*

I have a Dell Studio XPS 13 &  i recently purchased a Media Center Remote that came with a separate receiver - plugging in the receiver Windows automatically installed the drivers and the remote was active (though i was using it only with the receiver). A few days later i was trying the receiver on another machine on the same desk and noticed that pressing buttons on the remote would trigger the action on my XPS aswell as the machine the external receiver was plugged into.

So i'm assuming that:

1. If possible plug-in an external IR receiver. This should get windows to install the drivers.
2. Remove the receiver and the remote should work with your machine!